# Should I create another model or append columns to existing one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, devise

I have generated a `User` model via Devise( `rails generate devise User`) and now think how to tied it with other models in my app.

Is it OK to add additional columns to it, such as `country`, `user_name`, `link to avatar image`, `PayPal email address` or better to create another model, e.g. `Profile` and connect it with `User` via `belongs_to` relationship?

I need `Profile` model for later use in views. So current_user could see `profiles` of other users and change his own.

But if I use only Devise '`User` model (with columns from `Profile`), then when I want to edit my `profile` information, I would be redirected to Devise' route `/users/edit`and will see `password, email` fields.  But I did not want to edit them. I just wanted to edit my `profile` fields from `User` model.

So, is it better to create another model (`Profile`) or append fields to existing one(`User`)?

Comment: i would do that if there is a need. otherwise you could append more fields in a related model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that creating another model is the right way for you.

This way you will have separation between your user model which will mainly serve authentication purposes and the profile data which will mainly serve social purposes.

This will also allow you to load from the database only necessary data easily - you will be able to run `User.find` and get only basic user authentication data without integrating a select filter to get only needed fields. This is of course faster and more DB friendly.

Also, in the future, when you'd like to add other attributes related to users it would easier to separate them under their own logical namespace because you've already built your system this way.